# Federated prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, influxdb, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to have a federated Prometheus with remote storage(influxdb). I am new to Prometheus and monitoring. What is best way or design to implement the federated Prometheus?

Do we need to have Prometheus, alertmanager, influxdb, and grafana in each datacenter? or how do we need to design for the production environment?

Do we need to install all 4 (prometheus, alertmanager, influxdb and grafana) in one server or different servers in prod?

Answer (score 0):

I'll mention that you should not take all the data from your prometheuses from datacenters, it's not recommended. If you want to have a single endpoint to ask about metrics, check out Thanos/Cortex (if you don't have HA, also look into VictoriaMetrics). For designing and implementing Federation, check [here](https://www.robustperception.io/federation-what-is-it-good-for).

So actually you need to have only 1 grafana. Prometheus and alertmanager (in HA mode) in each DC seems reasonable. About influx, it depends on your usage.

About installation on different servers. Installing alertmanager on the same server as Prometheus wouldn't be that bad. I would for sure separate Influxdb.

Comment: And one more question, If I have read/write API(influxdb) in Prometheus config and choose Prometheus as a data source in grafana. Will grafana gets data from prometheus (local storage) or from influxdb since i have read API on prometheus config?

Comment: AFAIK from influx

Comment: FYI, VictoriaMetrics also supports collecting data from Prometheus HA pairs - see [these docs](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/blob/master/README.md#high-availability).

Comment: @valyala AFAIK VictoriaMetrics was not deduplicating, sth changed?

Comment: @Armatorix, [Promxy](https://github.com/jacksontj/promxy) in front of VictoriaMetrics replicas deduplicates the data as described in the docs above.

Comment: VictoriaMetrics gained  support for deduplication - see [these docs](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/blob/master/README.md#deduplication)